# What problems should I anticipate if I prefix order IDs with alphanumeric characters?

Tags: orders, multistore, stores

My client would like to prefix order IDs with descriptive multi-store abbreviations such as WS00000000 (Wholesale), AFF0000000 (Affiliate), RE00000000 (Retail), LS00000000 (Living Social), etc. Its purpose is to make communicating orders through phone support and fulfillment more efficient. Certain shipping rules and order history can be deemed by knowing the origin of the order.

I read another case of a developer attempting it on older versions of Magento as seen here:

http://chilipepperdesign.com/2009/07/09/changing-magento-order-invoice-and-shipping-numbers/

As I assumed, you would need to update all fields storing the order ID from *integer* to *text*. I understand that this might complicate upgrades but if I can turn this process of conversion into a script then I can reproduce this on future installs. What other unforeseen problems should I anticipate? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you from experience that there are no issues if you prefix the order numbers with letters.
You only need to do it right.

You need to change the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type
::fetchNewIncrementId` method for orders. Just let the orignal method do it's magic and prepend your prefix.

Comment: Thanks @marius! Will try that out today. Also, thanks for keeping this site in order. We appreciate your help!!